# Where should i put the DbContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, n-tier-architecture, dbcontext

Was wondering in which layer project i should put the DbContext implementation if i am working with an MVC 3 project which integrate 3 layers ( BusinessLogic, Persistence, Domain)

Should it be directly in the MVC 3 project ? or in persistence ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Persistence**, as it's responsible for persisting the data to the database.

If it *doesn't* belong there, what does?

Comment: Right. Sorry for such a stupid question lol. But sometime you watch the architecture and you tell yourself.. should it be ? but you right. Thanks.

Comment: @Rushino - no probs. Its a common mistake -> people go out looking to create additional projects/layers/tiers before actually thinking about what is to go there. Work out what your application is/will do, then decide how to break it up.